# Spark: GraphX fails to find connected components in graphs with few edges and long paths

Tags: apache-spark, spark-graphx, connected-components

I'm new to Spark and GraphX and did some experiments with its algorithm to find connected components. I noticed that the structure of the graph seems to have a strong impact on the performance.

It was able to compute graphs with millions of vertices and edges, but for a certain group of graphs, the algorithm did not finish in time, but eventually fails with an `OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`.

The algorithm seems to have problems with graphs that contain long paths. For instance, for this graph `{ (i,i+1) | i <- {1..200} }` the computation fails. However, when I added transitive edges, the computation finished immediately:

```
{ (i,j) | i <- {1..200}, j <- {i+1,200} }
```

Also graphs like this were no problem:

```
{ (i,1) | i <- {1..200} }
```

Here is a minimal example to reproduce the problem:

```
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.graphx._
import org.apache.spark.graphx.lib._
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel

import scala.collection.mutable

object Matching extends Logging {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val fname = "input.graph"
    val optionsList = args.drop(1).map { arg =>
      arg.dropWhile(_ == '-').split('=') match {
        case Array(opt, v) => opt -> v
        case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid argument: " + arg)
      }
    }
    val options = mutable.Map(optionsList: _*)

    val conf = new SparkConf()
    GraphXUtils.registerKryoClasses(conf)

    val partitionStrategy: Option[PartitionStrategy] = options.remove("partStrategy")
      .map(PartitionStrategy.fromString(_))
    val edgeStorageLevel = options.remove("edgeStorageLevel")
      .map(StorageLevel.fromString(_)).getOrElse(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY)
    val vertexStorageLevel = options.remove("vertexStorageLevel")
      .map(StorageLevel.fromString(_)).getOrElse(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY)

    val sc = new SparkContext(conf.setAppName("ConnectedComponents(" + fname + ")"))
    val unpartitionedGraph = GraphLoader.edgeListFile(sc, fname,
      edgeStorageLevel = edgeStorageLevel,
      vertexStorageLevel = vertexStorageLevel).cache()
    log.info("Loading graph...")
    val graph = partitionStrategy.foldLeft(unpartitionedGraph)(_.partitionBy(_))
    log.info("Loading graph...done")

    log.info("Computing connected components...")
    val cc = ConnectedComponents.run(graph)
    log.info("Computed connected components...done")

    sc.stop()
  }
}
```

The `input.graph` file can look this this (10 nodes, 9 edges connecting them):

```
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
5 6
6 7
7 8
8 9
9 10
```

When it fails, it hangs in `ConnectedComponents.run(graph)`. The error message is:

```
Exception in thread "dag-scheduler-event-loop" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1054)
    at java.lang.String.replace(String.java:2239)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getFormattedClassName(Utils.scala:1632)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.RDDInfo$$anonfun$1.apply(RDDInfo.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.RDDInfo$$anonfun$1.apply(RDDInfo.scala:58)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.RDDInfo$.fromRdd(RDDInfo.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.StageInfo$$anonfun$1.apply(StageInfo.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.StageInfo$$anonfun$1.apply(StageInfo.scala:80)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.StageInfo$.fromStage(StageInfo.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Stage.<init>(Stage.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapStage.<init>(ShuffleMapStage.scala:44)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.newShuffleMapStage(DAGScheduler.scala:317)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$newOrUsedShuffleStage(DAGScheduler.scala:352)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$getShuffleMapStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$getShuffleMapStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:285)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:742)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1194)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.mutable.Stack.foreach(Stack.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$getShuffleMapStage(DAGScheduler.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$visit$1$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:389)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$visit$1$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:386)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.visit$1(DAGScheduler.scala:386)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.getParentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:398)
```

I am running a local Spark node and start the JVM with the following options:

```
-Dspark.master=local -Dspark.local.dir=/home/phil/tmp/spark-tmp -Xms8g -Xmx8g
```

Can you help me understand why it has problem with this toy graph (201 nodes and 200 edges), but on the other hand can solve a realistic graph with multiple millions of edges in about 80 seconds? (In both examples, I use the same setup and configuration.)

**UPDATE:**

Can also be reproduced in the spark-shell:

```
import org.apache.spark.graphx._
import org.apache.spark.graphx.lib._

val graph = GraphLoader.edgeListFile(sc, "input.graph").cache()
ConnectedComponents.run(graph)
```

I created a bug report: [SPARK-15042](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-15042)

Comment: It is great! it seems it will fail in my case too (I'm still waiting). I took this case { (i,i+1) | i <- {1..200} }. Number of skipping tasks grows exponentially. I understand why It does 200 stages but dont know why does it fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [SPARK-15042](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-15042), the problem still exists in 2.1.0-snapshot.

The progress toward fixing the bug can be seen in [SPARK-5484](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5484).